# Исключение элемента, удовлетворяющего условию

Tags: c#, linq

Дана целочисленная последователньость А. Получить новую последовательность. Если порядковый номер элемента А делится на 3 нацело, то этот элемент в новую последователньость не включается; если остаток от деления порядкового номера на 3 равен 1, то в новую последовательность добавляется удвоенное значение этого элемента; в противном случае элемент добавляется в новую последовательность без изменений.

Как не включать элементы, делящиеся на 3? Какие способы существуют?

Comment: @Alex9, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Сделал всё, кроме не включения элементов с номерами, делящимися нацело на 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте перегрузку `Where`, которая кроме элемента предоставляет индекс элемента:

```
var list = new List<string>()
{
    "one", "two", "three", "four"
}

var newList = list.Where((s, i) => i % 3 != 0); // two, three
```

`newList` будет содержать элементы, индексы которых не делятся на три.